# Finding the foot of perpendicular of a point on the circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

P is a point on the circumcircle of a triangle ABC. Foot of perpendicular from P on AB and AC are (0, 0), (3, 3) respectively. If the foot of perpendicular from P to BC (whose equation is
3x + 2y + 5 = 0) is (a, b) then (a + b) is equal to :

(A) 2

(B) –2

(C) –1

(D) 0

My approach is as follow

Please refer to the figure below
The line BC and the coordinate (0,0) and (3,3) is positioned, As it is a circumcircle the point P, A , B and C lies on the same circle. The projection of $P(\alpha,\beta)$ is shown in the figure where as the projection of $P(\alpha,\beta)$ on AB is (0,0) and projection of  $P(\alpha,\beta)$ on AC is (3,3). How we will find the actual coordinates of each points

[image]

Comment: Direct solution with analytic geometry leads to fifth order equation. I believe one needs to use property that three projection points are collinear.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line